# Can the definite integral be written as the difference of two integrals with lower limits of $-\infty$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

My question is: Can $\int_a^b f(x)dx$ be written as

$$\int_a^b f(x)\ dx = \int_{-\infty}^b f(x)dx - \int_{-\infty}^a f(x)dx$$ or is a limiting process required ??

Comment: Try it for $f(x) = 1$ ...

Comment: So then a limiting process is required. no?

Comment: I mean replace $-\infty$ with $c\rightarrow -\infty$ and take the limits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all 3 integrals exist, the equality will hold. But it is very much possible for the definite integral to exist and the other two not.

Comment: What about @Martin R 's example $f(x)=1$ in the comments?

Comment: @user45664 That's exactly what I mean. The definite integral exists, but both improper ones don't. If all 3 integrals exist, they will match.